# CUDA - Multiple parallel reductions sometimes fail

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, reduction

I have the following problem. I have implemented several different parallel reduction algorithms and all of them work correctly if I'm reducing just **one** value per kernel. But now I need to reduce several **(21)** and I've just no idea why it's working sometimes and sometimes not.

The steps performed are:

- calculating the relevant values per thread (in the example I simply set them to 1 since it's showing the same behavior)
- load them into shared memory
- sync my threads within the block
- reduce the values down in shared memory

Here is the complete code that you can just cpy&pst and run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

// switch the compiler flag if you don't have the sdk's helper_cuda.h file
#if 1
#include "helper_cuda.h"
#else
#define checkCudaErrors(val) (val)
#define getLastCudaError(msg)
#endif

#ifdef __CDT_PARSER__
#define __global__
#define __device__
#define __shared__
#define __host__
#endif

// compute sum of val over num threads
__device__ float localSum(const float& val, volatile float* reductionSpace, const uint& localId)
{
    reductionSpace[localId] = val;  // load data into shared mem
    __syncthreads();

    // complete loop unroll
    if (localId < 128) reductionSpace[localId] += reductionSpace[localId + 128];
    __syncthreads();

    if (localId < 64) reductionSpace[localId] += reductionSpace[localId + 64];
    __syncthreads();

    // within one warp (=32 threads) instructions are SIMD synchronous
    // -> __syncthreads() not needed
    if (localId < 32)
    {
        reductionSpace[localId] += reductionSpace[localId + 32];
        reductionSpace[localId] += reductionSpace[localId + 16];
        reductionSpace[localId] += reductionSpace[localId + 8];
        reductionSpace[localId] += reductionSpace[localId + 4];
        reductionSpace[localId] += reductionSpace[localId + 2];
        reductionSpace[localId] += reductionSpace[localId + 1];
    }

    ## Edit: Here we need to sync in order to guarantee that the thread with ID 0 is also done... ##
    __syncthreads();

    return reductionSpace[0];
}

__global__ void d_kernel(float* od, int n)
{
    extern __shared__ float reductionSpace[];
    int g_idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    const unsigned int linId = threadIdx.x;
    __shared__ float partialSums[21];

    float tmp[6] =
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    // for simplification all computations are remove - this version still shows the same behaviour
    if (g_idx < n)
    {
        tmp[0] = 1.0f;
        tmp[1] = 1.0f;
        tmp[2] = 1.0f;
        tmp[3] = 1.0f;
        tmp[4] = 1.0f;
        tmp[5] = 1.0f;
    }

    float res = 0.0f;
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < 6; ++j, ++c)
        {
            res = tmp[i] * tmp[j];
            // compute the sum of the values res for blockDim.x threads. This uses
            // the shared memory reductionSpace for calculations
            partialSums[c] = localSum(res, reductionSpace, linId);

        }
    }
    __syncthreads();

    // write back the sum values for this block
    if (linId < 21)
    {
        atomicAdd(&od[linId], partialSums[linId]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int w = 320;
    int h = 240;
    int n = w * h;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    float *d_out;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_out, 21 * sizeof(float)));
    float* h_out = new float[21];

    int dimBlock = 256;
    int dimGrid = (n - 1) / dimBlock + 1;
    int sharedMemSize = dimBlock * sizeof(float);

    printf("w: %d\n", w);
    printf("h: %d\n", h);
    printf("dimBlock: %d\n", dimBlock);
    printf("dimGrid: %d\n", dimGrid);
    printf("sharedMemSize: %d\n", sharedMemSize);

    int failcounter = 0;
    float target = (float) n;
    int c = 0;
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // run the kernel for 200 times
    for (int run = 0; run < 200; ++run)
    {
        cudaMemset(d_out, 0, 21 * sizeof(float));
        d_kernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock, sharedMemSize>>>(d_out, n);;
        getLastCudaError("d_kernel");

        checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(h_out, d_out, 21 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

        // check if the output has target value
        // since all threads get value 1 the kernel output corresponds to counting the elements which is w*h=n
        bool failed = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 21; ++i)
        {
            if (abs(h_out[i] - target) > 0.01f)
            {
                ++failcounter;
                failed = true;
            }
        }

        // if failed, print the elements to show which one failed
        if (failed)
        {
            c = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = i; j < 6; ++j, ++c)
                {
                    printf("%10.7f ", h_out[c]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    printf("failcounter: %d\n", failcounter);

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    delete[] h_out;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_out));
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    return 0;
}
```

Some comments:

**BlockSize** is always **256** - so the unrolled loop in *localSum()* checks for the right threadIds.
Like mentioned at the beginning, out of 200 runs it's sometimes completely correct, sometimes only 2 values are wrong and sometimes 150 or so are wrong.

And it doesn't have to to anything with floating point precision since only *1x1* is multiplied and stored in the variable *res* in d_kernel(). I can clearly see that sometimes just some threads or blocks don't get started, but I don't know why. :/

Just from looking at the results it should be obvious that there is some kind of race-condition but I simply can't see the problem.

Has anyone an idea where the problem is?

### Edit:

I tested now a lot of things and I saw that it has to do something with the **BlockSize**. If I reduce it to smth **<=64** and change the *localSum()* accordingly then everything is working always as expected.

But that simply makes no sense to me?! I still do nothing else here than a normal parallel reduction with shared memory with the only difference that I do it 21 times per thread.

### Edit 2:

Now I'm completely confused. **The problem is unrolling the loop!!** Or better said **synchronizing the warp**. The following *localSum()* code works:

```
// compute sum of val over num threads
__device__ float localSum(const float& val, volatile float* reductionSpace, const uint& localId)
{
    reductionSpace[localId] = val;  // load data into shared mem
    __syncthreads();

    for (unsigned int s = blockDim.x / 2; s > 0; s >>= 1)
    {
        if (localId < s)
        {
            reductionSpace[localId] += reductionSpace[localId + s];
        }

        __syncthreads();
    }

    return reductionSpace[0];
}
```

But if I unroll the last warp and do not synchronize between the threads, I get again sometimes like 2 or 3 wrong results out of 2000 runs.
So the following code does **NOT** work:

```
// compute sum of val over num threads
__device__ float localSum(const float& val, volatile float* reductionSpace, const uint& localId)
{
    reductionSpace[localId] = val;  // load data into shared mem
    __syncthreads();

    for (unsigned int s = blockDim.x / 2; s > 32; s >>= 1)
    {
        if (localId < s)
        {
            reductionSpace[localId] += reductionSpace[localId + s];
        }

        __syncthreads();
    }

    if (localId < 32)
    {
        reductionSpace[localId] += reductionSpace[localId + 32];
        reductionSpace[localId] += reductionSpace[localId + 16];
        reductionSpace[localId] += reductionSpace[localId + 8];
        reductionSpace[localId] += reductionSpace[localId + 4];
        reductionSpace[localId] += reductionSpace[localId + 2];
        reductionSpace[localId] += reductionSpace[localId + 1];
    }

    return reductionSpace[0];
}
```

But how does that make sense, since CUDA executes one warp (32 threads) simultaneously and no __syncthreads() is needed?!

I don't need someone to post me working code here but I'm really asking someone with a lot of experience and deep knowledge in CUDA programming to describe me the underlying problem here. Or at least to give me a hint.

Comment: Without a complete repro case it will be just about impossible to say what the problem is.

Comment: I've updated my question with a complete example that you can just copy&paste and run.

Comment: Isn't your original localSum broken? Every warp can potentially return a different result, with only the first warp having the correct value.

Comment: Do you mean first warp or first thread? Bc the right value has only the first thread, but that's the one which is getting returned.
But you can also change localSum() so that every thread returns its sum and then check outside, when adding the sum to partialSums[c], if the threadID is 0. That does the same.

Comment: Perhaps you should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is so easy that I'm nearly ashamed to tell it. I was so blinded and looked everywhere but not at the most obvious code. A simple __syncthreads() was missing before the return statement in localSum(). Bc the last warp itself is beeing executed simultaneously but it's not guaranteed that the one with threadID 0 is done... Such a stupid mistake and I just didn't see it.

Sorry for all the trouble.. :)